# How can i connect to my elasticsearch cluster from another machine?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to connect my elasticsearch cluster from another machine i went through some documentation where they had mentioned that i had change the `network.bind_host : 0` .But i didn't find the `network.bind_host` in my elasticsearch.yml . I got only `network.host` in my elasticsearch.yml file.Even i tried it by giving as
`network.host :0` but i cant able to connect from another machine. And i also tried removing ## before `network.host :0` which throws an error when starting elasticsearch cluster.

When i am connecting from another machine i have to give `http://clustermachingip:9200` right?
Can anyone please help on this problem?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Set your network.host in elasticsearch.yml to 0.0.0.0 i.e. it will listen on all available bound addresses.

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Check your connectivity to the host machine on the port (in case you haven't changed the port it will be 9200).

In case you are not able to connect to the host machine still, I will suggest checking your `iptables` and allow connections to port 9200.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to connect to an elasticsearch instance of an another machine, yes the address is `http://clustermachingip:9200`. Can you try setting `network.bind_host: clustermachingip`

If this doesn't work then you might want to check the connectivity to the machine you are trying to connect to using something like a ping command.

```
ping clustermachingip
```

EDIT:

You can just start elasticsearch in one machine and try one of the following curl commands from the other machine.

```
curl 'clustermachingip:9200/_cat/nodes?v'
curl 'clustermachingip:9200/_cat/health?v'
```

EDIT2: Clearing out confusion between network.host, network.bind_host

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-network.html#advanced-network-settings

> The network.host setting explained in Commonly used network settings
>   is a shortcut which sets the bind host and the publish host at the
>   same time. In advanced used cases, such as when running behind a proxy
>   server, you may need to set these settings to different values:
>
> network.bind_host
>       This specifies which network interface(s) a node should bind to in order to listen for incoming requests. A node can bind to multiple
>   interfaces, e.g. two network cards, or a site-local address and a
>   local address. Defaults to network.host.  network.publish_host
>       The publish host is the single interface that the node advertises to other nodes in the cluster, so that those nodes can connect to it.
>   Currently an elasticsearch node may be bound to multiple addresses,
>   but only publishes one. If not specified, this defaults to the “best”
>   address from network.host, sorted by IPv4/IPv6 stack preference, then
>   by reachability.

Comment: Thanks.. In both machines the elasticsearch application need to be installed.Correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: No. Why would you want to install elasticsearch in both machines ?

Comment: you want me to change the `network.bind_host: clustermachineip` . Right now the elasticsearch cluster is running in my machine.So, in my `clustermachineip` i have to give my machineip address..

Comment: If your elasticsearch instance is running in your machine you can just use network.bind_host: localhost as well.

Comment: So,i have to change `network.bind_host: myipaddress` in elasticsearch.yml. But i didn't find network.bind_host in my elasticsearch.yml file . In that i can see only `network.host` setting.

Comment: What is the version you are using ?

Comment: Elasticsearch 2.4.0

Comment: read this docs please https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-network.html#advanced-network-settings